# Layouting a panel in C#: it works but why?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a panel (named picturePanel, see below) with a gridlayout (this is the brown square in the picture below), placed on a other panel, named bgPanel. I want the picturePanel to:

- Stay square at all times
- Maximize available space
- Stay within screen boundaries
- So if height<= width, choose height, else choose width

I did not succeed in doing this by using Aspect ratio fitter and anchors. Since I could not find my case in this or other forums, I combined a number of answers I found, see code below.

I tested this on ten different screen size and it works in these cases, but I don’t understand any longer why. Now I am afraid there are screen layouts for which it wouldn’t work.

**So my questions are:**

- Why is `int parentPanel.rect.width` not equal to `Screen.Width` ?
- How come that `int picturePanelSize = maxWidth<= maxHeight ? maxWidth :  maxHeight`;
- Does result in the correct sizing of the panel while the width is NOT based on Screen.Width and and height IS based on Screen.Height?

```
void Update()
{
    if (!hasPicturePanelSizeBeenSet)
    {
        SetPicturePanelSize();
        ResizePictures();
        hasPicturePanelSizeBeenSet = true;
    }
}
```

```
private void SetPicturePanelSize()
{
    RectTransform picturePanel = (RectTransform)HelperMethods.Find("PicturePanel", typeof(RectTransform));
    RectTransform parentPanel = (RectTransform)HelperMethods.Find("BgPanel", typeof(RectTransform));//BgPanel is the parent of PicturePanel

    int maxWidth =(int) parentPanel.rect.width;
    int maxHeight = (int)(Screen.height - picturePanel.position.y+picturePanel.sizeDelta.y);
    int picturePanelSize = maxWidth<= maxHeight ? maxWidth :  maxHeight;

    picturePanel.SetSizeWithCurrentAnchors(RectTransform.Axis.Horizontal, picturePanelSize);
    picturePanel.SetSizeWithCurrentAnchors(RectTransform.Axis.Vertical, picturePanelSize);

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ajlb.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kel61.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DR39u.png)